# Accessing session value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, session, playframework

In Playframework I have stored a value in session by:

```
Ok("Success").withSession( request.session +("userid" ->ses2))
```

My `userid` is in the form of:

```
ba1099c8-5799-415e-bfe6-3b1f7186062e
```

Now I am trying to use this session value in JavaScript by using:

```
var userid=@session.get("userid")
```

But I get error in JavaScript as:

```
Invalid or unexpected token var userid=ac86ac73-dd76-497a-a159-46e60be17ba9
```

Please tell me how can I solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Strings require quotes

Comment: When I store it in session with quotes I get an error 

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &                            

var userid=&quot;ac86ac73-dd76-497a-a159-46e60be17ba9&quot;

Comment: Not html entities....actual quotes. Javascript is not html. You would store the string in your session but in order to pass to javascript variable that is where the output needs to be quoted

Comment: I have converted it into string by 
var ses2 = request.body.toString()
and then storing it in session and if not this then how could i quote the output to use it in javasrcipt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `session.get("userid")` returns something like `1111` (without quotes), try either:

```
var userid="@session.get("userid")"
```

or

```
var userid=@Html(""" "${session.get("userid")}" """)
```